# Coverting a list of products to a list of strings

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation, map, rule

I am trying to find a way of converting a product of variables to a string, eg. if I have `abc...` I wish to obtain `"abc..."`. I also wish to be able to thread this operation over a list.

I have achieved the desired results by applying the following rule `Times[x_,y_]:>StringJoin[ToString/@{x,y}]` on a list of products. This works perfectly for products of two variables.

The natural generalization to product of arbitrary number of variables seems to be `Times[x__]:>StringJoin[ToString/@{x}]`. But when I apply the generalized version to the list of products (of two terms), it doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

```
mono={AAaa^2,AAaa AAbb,AAaa ABab,AAaa ABba,AAaa BAab,AAaa BAba,AAaa BBaa,AAaa BBbb,AAbb^2,AAbb ABab,AAbb ABba,AAbb BAab,AAbb BAba,AAbb BBaa,AAbb BBbb,ABab^2,ABab ABba,ABab BAab,ABab BAba,ABab BBaa,ABab BBbb,ABba^2,ABba BAab,ABba BAba,ABba BBaa,ABba BBbb,BAab^2,BAab BAba,BAab BBaa,BAab BBbb,BAba^2,BAba BBaa,BAba BBbb,BBaa^2,BBaa BBbb,BBbb^2}
c1=mono/.Power[x_,y_]:>StringRepeat[ToString[x],y]/.Times[a_,b_]:>StringJoin[ToString/@{a,b}]//FullForm
c2=mono/.Power[x_,y_]:>StringRepeat[ToString[x],y]/.Times[a__]:>StringJoin[ToString/@{a}]//FullForm
```

Comment: I must be missing something; I'm not sure the `Times[...] :> ...` parts are doing anything in `c1` or `c2`, since the expression in `ReplaceAll` only contains strings...? Also, what do you consider a "variable" here? Thanks!

Comment: There are two consecutive `ReplaceAll`s. The first one converts some elements of the list into strings, while the second one is supposed to convert the remaining elements into strings. `AAaa`  and every other four lettered word is a variable.

Comment: Ah, I see now, thanks. I think `HoldPattern[Times[a__]]` should make it work (`Times[a__]` evaluates to `a__`, which is why I think it's not matching anything).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks a lot.